# Make a cloth influenced by fluid?

Tags: physics, fluid-simulation, cloth-simulation

[image]I´d like to have a mesh, which behaves like a cloth, cotton or so which is in front of a tube, in which I simulate water. Now when the water exits the tube, I want the cloth (which is pinned at two vertices at the top) to move away. I added a sketch for a better understanding. The tube with the water in it works and it also enters the tube. But I have problems regarding the cloth...

I tried two different options.

a) Just cloth physics, the water didn´t recognize an obstacle and passed right through it

b) Cloth physics + Obstacle (Shell), the water was stopped by the cloth, didn´t exit the tube and the cloth also didn´t move except of the motion at the beginning, when it "fell" into the Pin-Points.

Does anyone have an idea how I can realize that?

Thanks a lot in advance!
Jens

Comment: As far as I know Blender doesn't support any type of physics interactions of different types, look for something more advanced

Comment: Okay. Thanks a lot for your answer. That was also what I heart. But I thought maybe there is a possibility. :-( Thank you.

Comment: It wouldn't be physically accurate, but you could try adding a wind force field to affect the cloth as soon as the water hits it. Put a little turbulence in the force field settings to make it look more watery.

Comment: Hi kaisa! Thanks a lot for your hint. I try to simulate something more or less physically correct for a masters-thesis. At the beginning I was optimistic to realize it with blender, but now I doubt, it´ll work. I think blender is not the right choice for what I need. :-)